# Apache errors on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, apache

After spending many hours (no joke) following several "How to install Apache on Sierra" and reading and trying countless questions and answers I've found on the web, Apache still doesn't work. Trying localhost/~myusername I get "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect."

`sudo apachectl restart` seems to work, but has no effect

`apachectl configtest` produced many different errors that I to the best of my abilities tried to fix, but it didn't fix the problem and the next apachectl configtest produced a different error - and so on...

The latest one:

```
[Thu Aug 31 23:48:00.748500 2017] [core:warn] [pid 84060] AH00117: Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType in line 366 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 23 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf:
<Directory> directive requires additional arguments
```

I didn't touch autoindex. I've already lost almost all hope.

On my wife's old desktop with El Capitan I've started Apache, PHP and MySQL in less that half an hour. What is this curse on Sierra?

I suspect I've screwed up majestically somewhere and would be happy to start from the beginning, on clean slate - but have no idea how.

Haven't found usable info on re-installing Apache on the web.

Update: Adding code from httpd.conf that seems to be causing the issue...

```
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document 
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions. 
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is 
# a good value. If most of your content is binary, such as applications 
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to 
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are 
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain
```

Comment: Could you show us line 366 of httpd.conf? And for context perhaps five lines that are before and after that line?

Comment: Actually based on this (https://gist.github.com/johnfoderaro/14021081b659bca5848df003de577a11) the default httpd.conf file in Sierra (10.12.2 at least) doesn't mention "DefaultType" at all. Did you replace the original file with a conf from a website?

Comment: Line 336 is that has "Default type text/plain"

'# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain'

Comment: I've sorry - I never posted here. How do I post code so the formatting is preserved?

I followed so many suggestions that now I have several back-ups for

Comment: If you check the very top of that httpd.conf file I think you'll see lines that hint that the conf file is intended for Apache HTTPD 2.2 while Sierra uses 2.4. My guess is that the problem here is mainly that you have a httpd.conf file intended for an older release. The first step to a fix might be simply to start again with the original httpd.conf file that comes with Sierra. Do you have a copy of the original httpd.conf that was part of the Sierra install?

Comment: "Refused to connect" means it's blocking you.  Is Apache running and if so, do you have a firewall running?  What do you get if you try just browsing `localhost`?

Comment: @  Alistair McMillan - I've just updated from Yosemite and then the trouble began. Unfortunately I have several httpd.conf that popped from my attempts to follow suggestions. Here are all these files ( names copied from desktop) ;       httpd.conf
httpd.conf-afterupdate
httpd.conf.bak
httpd.conf.sierra
httpd.conf~previous
httpd.confTRY-
httpdSUSPECT.conf

Comment: @Allan  -  No firewalls.  When I use sudo apachectl restart  it seems to work. When I try http://localhost/~alexei I get the error I posted - "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect."

Comment: I've set hidden files to display, so I see all them on the desktop. Can I use BBEdit to edit or at least look into them? I have very limited knowledge of Terminal commands. I always try to copy them from posts and it could be what cause all the trouble.
There is a folder "original" with httpd.conf and Extra folder in it. Is it from Yosemite?

Comment: @Allan - localhost produces the same error.

Comment: Join me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64954/chat-about-apache-errors-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: Do you load mod_userdir? And have you updated httpd-userdir.conf to include your userdirs?

Comment: @ root  For some reason by mistake I've created another account and couldn't comment with it. Finally logged out and logged in with my correct account>
Please excuse my dumb questions, although I've successfully configured Apache on older MacOS'es, I've just followed the published guides and it was it.
This time I was doing the same, but I'm still not an experienced Terminal user.
You ask: "Do you load mod_userdir?" I've uncommented all lines as instructed, repeated the whole procedure 3 times.
I never touched http-userdir.conf, don't think it was mentioned in any guides I've tried.

Comment: Is it possible to reinstall Apache from a blank slate? I'm worried that because of following too many suggestions on other sites (sometimes contradicting each other) and being tired I could have made errors and now cannot find where they are.